# Automatic change of the extension icon after switching to the website

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to write a chrome extension which after each click and page load automatically retrieves the page address and runs a script that automatically changes the extension icon. My code changes the icon only after clicking the extension icon. How to make the icon change automatically after switching to the website

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2, 
  "name" : "__MSG_extName__",
  "default_locale" : "en",
  "version": "1.0",

  "permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ],  
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "images/icon.png",
    "default_popup": "index.html"
  }
}
```

**script.js**

```
chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'windowId': chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_CURRENT},
   function(tabs){ 
      var url = tabs[0].url;
      if (url.indexOf('mywebsite.com') !== -1){
           chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path:"images/ok.png"});
      }else{
          chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path:"images/no.png"});
      }
   }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to be notified when the page location changes, you should listen to the `chrome.tabs.onUpdated` event. 
 See the [Official Documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onUpdated) for details, but the idea would be, listen to that event, and when fired, check to see if the tab is the one you care about (for example, the active tab) and see if the changed value is the URL, and if so, compare against `mywebsite.com`.  Your code right now is only checking once, when you run the query.

Your code might look something like this:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
   const newUrl = changeInfo.url;
   if (newUrl) {
       if (newUrl.indexOf('mywebsite.com') !== -1){
           chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path:"images/ok.png"});
       }else{
           chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path:"images/no.png"});
       }
   }
});
```

Comment: After switching to another page, the no.png icon does not change

Comment: Do you mean switching to another tab?  In that case you will also need to pay attention to a change in active tab, try using [chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onActivated)

Comment: Yes. Po użyciu chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener działa dzięki.